# how to get tkinter messagebox pop in front of toplevel in class

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to get the messagebox to appear in front of the toplevel?
code:
`showwarning('warning','input four parameters!')` shows the messagebox in front of mainwindow not toplevel window.
I checked the similar question `root = Tk() texto = Toplevel(root) showinfo("title", "message")` and the solution is ,`showinfo("title", "message",parent=texto)`
while I use class,there is no parent defination.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import os

currentpath=os.path.dirname(__file__)
class AcurateQueryWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,all_node_list:list):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("AcurateQuery")
        self.width = 600
        self.heigh = 500
        self.screenwidth = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.screenheight = self.winfo_screenheight()
        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d'%(self.width, self.heigh, (self.screenwidth-self.width)/2, (self.screenheight-self.heigh)/2))
        self.resizable(0,0) 
        self.focus_set() 
        self.all_node_list = all_node_list
        self.acurate_query_node_list=[]
        self.setup_UI()

    def setup_UI(self):
        self.Style01 = Style()
        self.Style01.configure("title.TLabel", font=("Helvetica", 25, "bold"), foreground="navy")
        self.Style01.configure("pass.TLabel", font=("Helvetica", 15, "bold"), foreground="navy")
        self.Style01.configure("TButton", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"))
        self.Login_image = PhotoImage(file=currentpath+ os.sep + "img" + os.sep + "stu_detail_banner.png")
        self.Label_image = Label(self, image=self.Login_image)
        self.Label_image.pack()

        # title
        self.Label_title = Label(self, text="==AcurateQuery==", style="title.TLabel")
        self.Label_title.place(x=280, y=15)

        # pane
        self.Pane_detail = PanedWindow(self, width=590, height=380)
        self.Pane_detail.place(x=5, y=88)

        # 
        self.Label_rlinemin = Label(self.Pane_detail,text = "rlinemin:",style = "pass.TLabel")
        self.Label_rlinemin.place(x=160,y=70)
        self.var_rlinemin = StringVar()
        self.Entry_rlinemin = Entry(self.Pane_detail,textvariable = self.var_rlinemin , font=("Helvetica", 15, "bold"),width = 12)
        self.Entry_rlinemin.place(x=280,y=68)

        # 
        self.Label_rlinemax = Label(self.Pane_detail, text="rlinemax:",style = "pass.TLabel")
        self.Label_rlinemax.place(x=160, y=120)
        self.var_rlinemax = StringVar()
        self.Entry_rlinemax = Entry(self.Pane_detail,textvariable=self.var_rlinemax, font=("Helvetica", 15, "bold"), width=12)
        self.Entry_rlinemax.place(x=280, y=118)

        # 
        self.Label_rpointmin = Label(self.Pane_detail, text="rpointmin:",style = "pass.TLabel")
        self.Label_rpointmin.place(x=160, y=170)
        self.var_rpointmin = StringVar()
        self.Entry_rpointmin = Entry(self.Pane_detail,textvariable=self.var_rpointmin, font=("Helvetica", 15, "bold"), width=12)
        self.Entry_rpointmin.place(x=280, y=168)

        # 
        self.Label_rpointmax = Label(self.Pane_detail, text="rpointmax:",style = "pass.TLabel")
        self.Label_rpointmax.place(x=160, y=220)
        self.var_rpointmax = StringVar()
        self.Entry_rpointmax = Entry(self.Pane_detail,textvariable=self.var_rpointmax, font=("Helvetica", 15, "bold"), width=12)
        self.Entry_rpointmax.place(x=280, y=218)
        # 
        self.Button_save = Button(self, text="query", style="TButton",command = self.query)
        self.Button_save.place(x=300, y=452)
        self.Button_exit = Button(self, text="close", style="TButton",command = self.close_window)
        self.Button_exit.place(x=450, y=452)

    def close_window(self):
        self.destroy()

    def query(self):
        if len(self.Entry_rlinemin.get())==0 or len(self.Entry_rlinemax.get())==0 or len(self.Entry_rpointmin.get())==0 or len(self.Entry_rpointmax.get())==0:
            showwarning('warning','input four parameters!')
            pass
        else:
            rlinemin=int(str(self.Entry_rlinemin.get()).strip())
            rlinemax=int(str(self.Entry_rlinemax.get()).strip())
            rpointmin=int(str(self.Entry_rpointmin.get()).strip())
            rpointmax=int(str(self.Entry_rpointmax.get()).strip())
            if rlinemin>rlinemax or rpointmin>rpointmax:
                showwarning('warning','max must bigger than min')
            else:
                self.acurate_query_node_list.append([rlinemin,rlinemax,rpointmin,rpointmax])
                self.destroy()
                return self.acurate_query_node_list
```

Is there a way to get the messagebox to appear in front of the toplevel while I use class?

Comment: Use `parent=self`.

Comment: self.？，i used self.AcuratQueryWindow,not work

Comment: No, just `self`